# How do you use 'basic markup' in a webform default value?

Tags: webforms

How can you use 'basic markup' in a webform default value? The goals is to format the default text.

Steps

1. Create a Basic HTML element
2. Edit the element
3. Using the 'advanced' tab set the default value.

Only plain text is allowed in this field. Any markup is rendered as markup not as HTML

[image: Markup element default]

Comment: 1. I tried to add it, but [Markup element doesn't exist...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fspnN.png). So if you're 100% sure that's the name of it, then either a custom or contrib module is adding such element.

Comment: Sorry, it is 'Basic HTML'

Comment: [I don't have that default value option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxckQ.png) so looks like that was added via custom or contrib module. You'll need to find the form code add add the `#format` key to the array. [As shown here](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor/issues/1031160#comment-4085946)